# Time-inhomogeneous and state dependent Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

We look at an inhomogeneous Markov chain $X_{n}$ that evolves according to the following transition probabilities:
$$
P(X_{n+1}=k+1|X_{n}=k)=\frac{f(k)}{n+1}\\
P(X_{n+1}=k|X_{n}=k)=\frac{n-f(k)}{n+1}\\
P(X_{n+1}=1|X_{n}=k)=\frac{1}{n+1},
$$
where f is a (sub)linear function.

I am now looking for an upper bound for $|P(X_{n+1}\geq k)-P(X_{i}\geq k)|$.
Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

Thanks very much!